# While Project Creation How to automatically generate a Key

Tags: c#, algorithm, asp.net-core, c#-4.0

I am creating a project using asp.net core. My model class have 2 properties

1. ProjectName
2. Key

When I entered the project name in projectName field. It automatically generate key value and that value display to Key field
I explained my doubt in screenshot:
[Auto Generate Project Key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGvip.png)

Anyone know the algorithm or c# code for searching and display auto generate key based on project name let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If projects names based on `PascalCase` you can generate project keys like this :

```
var projectName = "TemoManagmentProejct"; // Any project name that based on Pascal Case

        //Separate name by capital letters
        var projectKeyLetters =
            projectName
                .Where(p => char.IsUpper(p))
                .ToArray();

        //Add last project name letter to end of project key and make it capital
        var projectKey =
            new string(projectKeyLetters) +
            char.ToUpper(projectName.Last());
```

and the result will be : TMPT

[image]